# No ping between hosts in mininet when ran mininet

Tags: mininet

I have install mininet and then have run it but there are no ping between hosts.

```
ali@ubuntu:~$ sudo mn

No default OpenFlow controller found for default switch!

Falling back to OVS Bridge

Creating network

Adding controller

Adding hosts:
h1 h2 

Adding switches:
s1 

Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s1) 

Configuring hosts
h1 h2 

Starting controller


Starting 1 switches
s1 ...

Starting CLI:

mininet> pingall

Ping: testing ping reachability

h1 -> X 

h2 -> X 

Results: 100% dropped (0/2 received)
```

Comment: It looks like you running Python script. If you share the snippet, it would be helpful to find a cause.

Answer (score 0):

"No default OpenFlow controller found for default switch!"

There is no ping between hosts because there is no controller to your network.
You need a Controller even to guide switches to "act_like_switch" or "act_like_hub". Else switches will not forward packets.

The problem is that you installed mininet but mininet doesn't find default controller for some reason.

- Try to run other controllers  or remote like [this](http://mininet.org/blog/2013/06/03/automating-controller-startup/)
- Execute again `mininet/util/install.sh`
- Try to deactivate `sudo service openvswitch-controller stop
  sudo update-rc.d openvswitch-controller disable` and  reconfigure : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openvswitch-datapath-dkms
  sudo service openflow-switch restart`
- Reinstall mininet if nothing works and follow all the [steps](http://mininet.org/download/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer